# WAMP 403 forbidden from external sources

Tags: php, apache, wamp, windows-server-2012

I have read a ton of threads here and elsewhere but none of the suggestions have worked. I installed the latest version of WAMP 64 bit on a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2.

- I created a subdirectory within the `www` directory called `andrew`. In that is an `index.html` file.
- I added the following to the hosts file:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 andrew
  ::1 andrew
  ```
- I added the following to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/andrew"
      ServerName andrew
      <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/andrew">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- I uncommented the virtual hosts line in httpd.conf
- I stopped and started net dnscache
- I restarted the WAMP services
- I "Put Online" the WAMP server

Regardless, when I access the server from another machine like `[server IP address]*/andrew/index.html` I get a `403 Forbidden` error.

Here is the apache error log ("[SERVER IP]" is really the server's actual IP):

```
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:32.628356 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4680:tid 424] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.656507 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4444:tid 312] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.672087 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4680:tid 424] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4444 exited successfully.
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.921723 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4724:tid 416] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.952892 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4724:tid 416] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.952892 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4724:tid 416] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 11:49:07
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.952892 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4724:tid 416] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.17\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:34.952892 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4724:tid 416] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4388
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:35.140157 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4388:tid 312] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:35.171357 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4388:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:49.899265 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 4388:tid 1040] [client 73.82.23.97:57193] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp64/www/andrew/index.html
[Fri Apr 22 17:10:50.055249 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 4388:tid 1040] [client 73.82.23.97:57193] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp64/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://[SERVER IP]/andrew/index.html
```

I am now thinking it has to do with some setting on Windows 2012 Server, but I can't figure it out. Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Apache doesn't know to associate the IP address with your virtual host, it uses the main server settings. Probably you don't need a virtual host at all, but try this anyway:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/andrew"
    ServerName andrew
    #of course, enter your IP address here
    ServerAlias 1.2.3.4
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/andrew">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well, that technically works. [Server IP]/andrew/index.html doesn't, but just entering http://[Server IP] goes straight to that folder. What I was hoping to do is have several different folders in the www directory, and set up vhost entries for each so users could visit IP/andrew, IP/foobar, etc.

Comment: But you've set your `DocumentRoot` to include the `andrew` folder, so you don't put it in your URL. I think you misunderstand what a virtual host is. As I said, you probably don't need one at all. Look up the `Alias` command in [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) instead. As implied by the name, a [virtual *host*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) allows you to have different host names on one server.

Comment: Ah. I was reading an article that said to use vhosts instead of Alias. I am admittedly a n00b when it comes to the web. I am a SQL Server developer by trade. Here is the article I was referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 0):

please don't forget to edit **phpMyAdmin.conf** file. It will save your time to face 403 Error (403 Forbidden). You should set *Require all granted* into it as follows (indipendently by used phpMyAdmin version):

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin5.0.2/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin5.0.2/">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```